# Python Scrapy only crawls start_urls and then stops. How to go deeper?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Why is it that Scrapy only crawls the start_urls and then stops? Is there a way to have Scrapy crawl through all pages in a directory tree of a website, such as http://www.example.com/directory? Or, is there a way to have Scrapy crawl deeper into all links on the start_urls pages?

```
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "dmoz"
        allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
        start_urls = [
                      "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
                      "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
                      ]

        rules = [
               Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('', )), follow=True),
               Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('', )), callback='parse_item')
               ]

        def parse_item(self, response):
          print response.url

        def parse(self, response):
          print response.url
```

Here's the code in my main.py file:

```
dmozSpider = DmozSpider()
spider = dmozSpider

settings = get_project_settings()

crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove parse() in the DmozSpider class and then parse_item() will get more than the start_urls

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @stevetronix's answer a bit:

You are not supposed to override the `parse()` method when using the `CrawlSpider`. You should set a custom `callback` in your `Rule` with a different name.
Here is the excerpt from the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.